# OpenLayers Icon className SVG - Change Fill Via CSS?

Tags: css, svg, openlayers

I'm trying to use CSS classes in openlayers to change an svg fill colour:

eg say in open layers I have

```
style = new Style({
                image: new Icon({
                    src: styleConfig.image.src,
                    scale: styleConfig.image.scale,
                    offset: [styleConfig.offsetX, styleConfig.offsetY],
                    className: 'icon--blue'
                }),
                zIndex: styleConfig.zIndex
            });
```

and then I have an SVG like so:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="49" height="44" viewBox="0 0 580 515" class="icon--blue"><circle fill="inherit" cx="475" cy="106.9" r="102.9"/><g class="cat"><circle fill="inherit" cx="475" cy="106.9" r="102.9"/></g></svg>
```

and some CSS like so:

```
.icon--blue circle {
fill: #0000ff !important;
}
.icon--blue .cat {
display: none;
}
```

Try as I might I cannot get the css based fill effect to be applied. I was wondering if this is supported?

Also the hiding of the grouping with the class name of "cat" also doesn't work.

Seeing is OpenLayers is rendering to canvas, debugging this kind of stuff is very difficult.

Comment: For this to work, the fill inside SVG should have `inherit` value.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't get me there

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately that didn't get me there. It doesn't seem like the CSS class is even having any effect. I'd say it is because although className exists, because Features use canvas in OL css classes have no effect

Comment: css applied to the original mage will not be reflected when it is drawn to canvas.  Instead you should use the color option in the OpenLayers icon style as in this example https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/icon-color.html

Answer (score 0):

Start with a Proof of Concept SVG in a JSFiddle or CodePen, to get your SVG and CSS selectors right.

Learn [CSS Specificity](https://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html) to understand why the `.inner` circle below is green and not red;

Most likely no need for fill attribute and hardly ever `!important`

```html
<style>
  svg {
    width: 25%;
  }
  circle {
    fill: green;
    stroke: red;
  }
  #outer {
    fill: blue;
  }
  .inner {
    fill: red;
  }
  .hidden {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
  <circle id="outer" cx="10" cy="10" r="8" />
  <g class="inner">
    <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="4" />
  </g>
  <circle class="hidden" cx="15" cy="15" r="4" />
</svg>
```